# Is there a way to write this program using another method than .hasNext?

Tags: java, break

> Write a program that asks a user to input a string.  Then asks a user to type in an index value(integer).  You will use the charAt( ) method from the string class to find and output the character referenced by that index.  Allow the user to repeat these actions by placing this in a loop until the user gives you an empty string.  Now realize that If we call the charAt method with a bad value (a negative value or a integer larger than the size of the string) an exception will be thrown.  Add the code to catch this exception, output a warning message and then continue with the loop

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("");
        String s;
        int ind;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        while(sc.hasNext())
        {
            s=sc.next();
            if(s.length()==0)
                break;
            ind=sc.nextInt();
            try {
                char ch=s.charAt(ind);
                System.out.println("Character is "+ch);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Bad index Error!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You could rely on assignment evaluating to the assigned value. Also, call `Scanner.hasNextInt()` before calling `Scanner.nextInt()`. Like,

```
System.out.println();
String s;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while (sc.hasNext() && !(s = sc.next()).isEmpty()) {
    if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        int ind = sc.nextInt();
        try {
            char ch = s.charAt(ind);
            System.out.println("Character is " + ch);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Bad index Error!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug; `sc.next()` cannot return an empty string in this code. Try editing it this way:

```java
while(sc.hasNext()) {
    s = sc.next();
    if(s.length() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Woah, Nelly!");
        break;
    }
    // ...
}
```

See if you can get the program to print "Woah, Nelly!" by entering a blank line, or anything else. I can't, and assuming I understand [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) correctly, it is impossible for the `if` condition to ever be true here (emphasis mine):

> Depending upon the type of delimiting pattern, empty tokens may be returned. For example, **the pattern `"\\s+"` will return no empty tokens** since it matches multiple instances of the delimiter. The delimiting pattern "\s" could return empty tokens since it only passes one space at a time.

This pattern `"\\s+"` is the default one, and you haven't set a different one, so your scanner should never return an empty token. So the strict answer to "is there a way to write this program without the `break` statement?" is: yes, you can just delete the `if(...) break;` code and it doesn't change the behaviour in any way.

However, that's not really a solution to your problem because it doesn't give the user a way to exit the program. You should use `nextLine()` instead of `next()` to allow reading a blank line from the user.

Comment: so sad that "Woah, Nelly!" can not be printed

Comment: I looked over it. Thankyou!